# Cannot get slidesCount from $ionicSlideBoxDelegate

Tags: angularjs, html, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am creating a mobile app with Ionic framework. I am using ion-slide-box

```
        <ion-slide-box class="slidebox" on-slide-changed="change(index)"> 
              <ion-slide>
                  <img src="img/johnson.jpg" id="album">
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                  <img src="img/eiston.jpg" id="album">
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                  <img src="img/vera.jpg" id="album">
              </ion-slide>
              <ion-slide>
                  <img src="img/max.jpg" id="album">
              </ion-slide>
        </ion-slide-box>
```

I want to know the total slide number

```
$scope.change= function(index){
    console.log('currentindex '+index);      //i get the correct current index
    console.log($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex());   //I get undefined
    alert($ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slidesCount());     //I get undefined
}
```

I tried a lot of things, nothing seems to be working with $ionicSlideBoxDelegate? Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `<ion-slides>` instead of `<ion-slide-box>`, then try to add a modal to slider param i.e:

```
<ion-slides  options="options" slider="data.slider">
    <ion-slide-page>
      <div><h1>some Text</h1></div>
    </ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
```

then in your controller you will use 'data.activeIndex' to get the current index using a handler as:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicSlides.slideChangeEnd", function(event, data){
   alert( data.activeIndex );
});
```

you can consult the doc:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlides/

Answer (score 0):

Ionic's new slide is derived from [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/).

According to ionic's [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSlideBox/) it is deprecated in favour of the newer component.

You will have to do a bit of research into how to use the newer component as it is not documented very well.